# Flutter Unit testing TextFormField access obscureValue

Tags: flutter, unit-testing, flutter-textformfield

So i have a TextFormField

```
Widget buildPassword() => TextFormField(
    key: const Key('passwordFormKey'),
    obscureText: true,
    maxLines: 1,
    initialValue: password,
    style: const TextStyle(
      color: Colors.blue,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
      fontSize: 20,
    ),
    decoration: const InputDecoration(
      border: OutlineInputBorder(),
    ),
    validator: (password) =>
    password != null && password.isEmpty ? 'The password cannot be empty' : null,
    onChanged: onChangePassword,
  );
```

And i want to check for initial value/state that the TextFormField is being obscured

But i can't find a way to check in my unit test that obscureText value from the TextFormField itself.

Any idea how to access it ?

```
testWidgets('Mail And Password are Empty and initialed correctly', (widgetTester) async {
    await widgetTester.pumpWidget(createWidgetUnderTest());
    final TextFormField mailField = widgetTester.widget<TextFormField>(find.byKey(const Key('mailFormKey')));
    final TextFormField passwordField = widgetTester.widget<TextFormField>(find.byKey(const Key('passwordFormKey')));
    
    expect(mailField.controller?.value, '');
    expect(passwordField.controller?.value, '');
    expect(mailField.initialValue, '');
    expect(passwordField.initialValue, '');

  });
```

Comment: obscureValue means?

Comment: The obscure bool on a TextFormField that hide text type in for a password field

Comment: @ShwetaChauhan Anyway i can be more precise or is it understable enough ?

Comment: I got it but I am also learning testing so need to check

Answer (score 1):

`TextFormField` uses `EditableText` to obscure it, it should be:

```
    testWidgets('Mail And Password are Empty and initialed correctly', (widgetTester) async {
    await widgetTester.pumpWidget(createWidgetUnderTest());
    final TextFormField mailField = widgetTester.widget<TextFormField>(find.byKey(const Key('mailFormKey')));
    final EditableText passwordField = widgetTester.widget<EditableText>(find.byKey(const Key('passwordFormKey')));
    
    expect(mailField.controller?.value, '');
    expect(passwordField.controller?.value, '');
    expect(mailField.initialValue, '');
    expect(passwordField.initialValue, '');
    expect(passwordField.obscureText, true);

  });
```

Answer (score 0):

There is `TextField` in `TextFormField` descendants, so you can find it:

```dart
    testWidgets('description', (widgetTester) async {
      await widgetTester.pumpWidget(
        MaterialApp(
          home: YourScreen(),
        ),
      );

      await widgetTester.pumpAndSettle();

      final testField = find.descendant(
        // Key of TextFormField
        of: find.byKey(const Key('TextFormField.Key')),
        matching: find.byType(TextField),
      );

      expect(widgetTester.widget<TextField>(testField).obscureText, true);
    });
```